# How can I remove the "Harrowed" condition?

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

Somehow Astarion has picked up the Harrowed condition; I'd like to remove it, but can find nothing about it online.
This is after I've completed a fight and all the enemies that might have cast it on me are dead.

[image: Harrowed condition]

Comment: [This thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/BaldursGate3/comments/15tmtw9/stuck_with_garrotted_debuff/) has a few possible solutions. Please let us know if any of them work.

Comment: Have you tried Greater Restoration or Remove Curse?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try killing him (or making him jump in a chasm) and then resurrecting him at camp.

Answer (score 2):

Most, if not all conditions will be removed after a Long Rest.

If that is not a luxury you can afford, you can try the spells *Remove Curse* or *Greater Restoration*. On rare occasions you can find a *Scroll of Remove Curse* in containers and shops.

- [Remove Curse](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Remove_Curse): "*This spell allows spellcasters to remove all curses afflicting a target through touch.*"
- [Greater Restoration](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Greater_Restoration): "*This spell allows spellcasters to removes Charm, Petrification, Stun, and Curses from a creature.*"

Note that I'm not certain these spells will help, as I haven't encountered the Harrowed condition myself, but these work for getting rid of most detrimental conditions.

[Here](https://bg3.wiki/wiki/Harrowed_(Condition)) is a page describing the condition (offering not much more than the description seen in your screenshot, though).

As [Pyritie points out in the comments](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/405124/in-baldurs-gate-3-how-can-i-remove-the-harrowed-condition/407422#comment568800_405124), you can also kill your character or have them be killed, and, using a Revivify scroll or spell, or through Withers, resurrect them, free of any afflictions.